# Where to put almost in a phrase?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I would like to add the word `almost` to the sentence but I am not sure if should be after we or after to.

```
   I was so grateful that we came to the same conclusion
```

Comment: It all depends on what you want ***almost*** to modify. It might be a bit of an unlikely thing to say, but there's nothing inherently incorrect about *"I was [**almost**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she+was+almost+grateful%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) grateful that we came to the same conclusion"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different meanings

*I was so grateful that we almost came to the same conclusion*

We did not come to a final conclusion, but what we DID conclude was the same.

*I was so grateful that we came to almost the same conclusion*

We did come to a final conclusion, but it was not identical

For example if we race:

*I was grateful that we almost reached the goal at the same time* - we both gave up before the end.

*I was grateful that we reached the goal almost at the same time* - we both reached the goal and it was within minutes of each other